# MySQL connection: globally or in object?

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, object

I have two PHP classes. One is for connecting to the database, building queries, executing them, and disconnecting from the database. The other class is for users: adding them, updating them, logging them in, etc.

I'm debating whether I should connect to the database on the page globally and use that connection (passing the database object into the method of the user object), or whether I should connect and disconnect from the database from within the a user method itself.

The advantage I see for connecting globally, is that once connected I have that connection available for executing multiple methods. The disadvantage is that I 7need to worry about passing the database object around.

The advantage of connecting within the method is that it's completely transparent, however, there might be 4 or 5 connections established and disconnected, which may lead to an overhead.

Is there a best practice for using either, or does it really depend on the amount of users and the server's specs e.g. memory, cpu, etc. The system needs to support up to about 1,000 users, so it's fairly small scale.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

-Ryan

Comment: I strongly recommend instantiating once and then injecting the connection into your objects. Try googling "PHP Dependency Injection."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that creates the connection on demand and provides access to the connection object:

```
function getDb()
{
    static $db;
    if (!$db) $db = ...;
    return $db;
}
```

Wrapped into class this approach is called `Singleton`

Comment: http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1304-how-use-singleton-design-pattern.html

Comment: Where does this function reside? In an object or globally?

Comment: @Ryan S.: you can either use just function or create a static method

Comment: Functions like these I would call a trap. They are even more worse than a global or static class database variable.

Comment: @hakre: how can singleton be worse than a global variable? ;-)

Comment: That function is not a singleton. But what's bad is the fact, that you can not inject any dependency, this static var in a function  construct is totally inflexible. I've seen functions like these killing the natural growth of applications. It's really a trap.

Comment: @hakre: the function **is** a singleton. The patterns says nothing about implementation details it just states that the implementation should provide global access and single instance (that is the original singleton pattern definition). The design patterns **may be** implemented using the paradigms other than Object Oriented one. (thanks for -1)

Comment: You don't need to fight over the word singleton here. The fact whether its a singleton or not isn't actually the point of the discussion, the point is why it is bad (and not why singletons are bad in general). *Next* to that singletons are pathetic liars.

Comment: @hakre: singletons **are** better than global variables, since they guarantee the single instance and that the variable cannot be replaced. It is not the best pattern to manage dependencies, but it is definitely the easiest one to introduce for newbies.

Comment: "You don't need to fight over the word singleton here" --- lol, really? Who said "That function is not a singleton"? You began definition wars, not me ;-P

Comment: My main point of critique is that the function (however you coin the name of somewhat patternesque it is the implementation of) is harmful. It should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: @hakre: it is not harmful for newbies. Singleton **is** better than global variables.

Comment: @zerkms: Oh you're so desperately wrong, one could not be more wrong. You have just replaced a global variable with a global function return value and you tell it's better? I would say you created an alias, that's all. Next to that you don't really explain what a singleton is and it's pros and cons - just saying because your comment suggests that you have newbies in mind, but infact, you don't have. And aliasing a global static you can't reach any longer is harmful when it's not necessary. **Especially functions like the one you outlined in your answer should be avoided at all cost.**

Comment: See as well [Singleton PHP - database handler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3277305/367456)

Comment: @hakre: dude, it is classic singleton implementation, RTFM. Also you don't understand that singleton is not only about a global access, but also is about a **single** instance. As I said - RTFM please. If you cannot get this - please stop trolling me, okay? Anyway, don't waste your time - I will not reply you here.

Comment: @zerkms: Read my lips. Don't suggest such functions to newbies. Never. Regardless if it follows a pattern or not. Just take it easy, drop such a suggestion. Otherwise get yourself a lift that you did something classic but not classy. But it's helping no one.

Comment: @hakre: don't suggest me what to suggest. I have my **personal** opinion based on my experience. You have another one - great, put it in an answer.

Comment: I'm just leaving a big warning sign instead because I've seen this in multiple projects to cause problems. That's why I need to warn about it otherwise I would neglect my **professional experience**. I'm not black and white only, so I'm quite laxe about global or even a single class instance, but a function of that structure in specific can cause a lot of harm for maintaining an application. That's it, not the point that it could be called xyz, but the point which concrete implementation has been suggested. A global for example offers a much more easy access to a seam when it comes to play.

Comment: For a function like this, the seam would be the function name or the classname only, which is harder to deal with and can be even not possible depending on how the application is structured. That's all.

Comment: @hakre: function and static method implementation are **the same** things. There is technically **NO DIFFERENCE** between function and static method. I cannot understand why you accept static method implementation but against of function.

Comment: "For a function like this, the seam would be the function name or the classname only, which is harder to deal with and can be even not possible depending on how the application is structured" --- **this is singleton**. The function is implemented according design pattern idea (single instance access in global space). That's all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5786/discussion-between-zerkms-and-hakre)

Comment: @markus-tharkun: this is a bad comment - it doesn't have any explanations. Don't believe him. And, dude, have you ever tried to explain DI to completely newbies? PS: static is not even close to global. There are a lot of differences between them (which make static much better and acceptable)

Comment: Agree that it wasn't a good comment and that's why I removed it. But I still think, even in this particular case, constructor injection is doable without half a year of studying DI and a really good answer would incorporate that solution too.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, the best practice is to take the global approach.  This is mainly due to the fact that repeated connects/disconnects to the MySQL server can cause a *significant* decrease in performance.

In fact, though this may seem counter-intuitive, most PHP experts (including myself) recommend that you avoid using mysql_close() altogether, unless there's a pressing reason not to.  This is because that is handled automatically in PHP's cleanup anyway, so adding mysql_close() just creates a further deterioration in performance.

Comment: The global approach is never a good practice in any programming language, since it is very difficult to manage

Comment: I disagree with this answer. As @zerkms noted, the global approach is not a good idea. Only connecting to the database once is a good idea, but there are better ways to do it that don't clutter the global namespace and make testing impossible. Using the singleton pattern is one way, though it also makes testing difficult. Look into dependency injection or try something like zerkms's function.

Comment: @rdlowrey: +1, but DI is a complex solution, which implies deep theoretical knowledge and experience, as well as code testing itself. So personally I'd prefer singleton as a first step to good design ;-)

Comment: @zerkms You're probably right ... it's said the first design pattern people learn is usually the singleton. It's a good place to start.

Comment: @rdlowrey I think what Ryan was referring to when he used the word "global" was not assigning the connection handler to a global variable (which I would agree is not a good idea!), but rather only creating the connection once, then passing that db object around as-needed without connecting/disconnecting to/from MySQL each time.  That's what my answer was specifically addressing.  =)

Comment: @KrisCraig yes, that's what I was referring to :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely keep track of and reuse a single connection in your base DB class. The above is a good example of creating and returning that connection as needed from the DB class.

To make accessing that connection easier from your actual objects, you could then create a base object class (called DBable or something) which calls getDb in its constructor and assign that to a local $db variable inside that class. Then, all your objects which need database access can extend that DBable class, and always have a $db reference available implicitly without needing to remember to call getDb everywhere.

Comment: Not a bad idea but PHP's lack of multiple inheritance makes using a parent class for this functionality problematic. Perhaps an interface would be better in this instance?

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance. Entity **is not** a database. So - don't inherit it.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm debating whether I should connect to the database on the page globally and use that connection (passing the database object into the method of the user object), or whether I should connect and disconnect from the database from within the a user method itself.

Stop debating. Make the database class available to the functions that need it and handle the connection transparently, so that you have one connection per request. Doing multiple connects / disconnects is superfluous and only creates too much work that does not need to be done.

So actually you only need one connection variable (object). Make it available to the functions that need it (e.g. a database class that has it as a member) and you're fine. Whether or not you make that object globally available is your design decision.

Additionally take a look into a pattern called [*table data gateway*](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) and / or the [active record pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html). Probably that's what you do with your user object, so you don't need to re-invent the wheel and you can take an existing library instead so you can better concentrate on the actual work that needs to be done in your application.

Comment: `Make the database class available to the functions that need it` --- classes in php are always available since they are declared in a global space. You must have been speaking about `database class instance, thus object`, haven't you?

Comment: Depends how it is implemented, can differ based on implementation so must not be right nor wrong.

Comment: the question is **about implementation**. Your answer adds nothing to the original discussion. OP knows he need to implement it in some way but doesn't know how. Neither your answer explains that.